# I'm trying to do a search/replace using regex for mass replacing on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace, mass-assignment

I need to add a parameter for each code and name, i tried using (.+) or (.*) for each number, but it didnt work. Each space means that is a different number and not every space has the same width. Example from this:

> Abanda CDP 192 129 58 0 0 0 2 3 3
>   2.998 0.013   33.091627 -85.527029 2582661

To this:

> Abanda CDP |code1=192 |code2=129 |code3=58 |code4=0 |code5=0 |code6=0 |code7=2 |code8=3 |code9=3
>   |code9=2.998 |code10=0.013    |code11=33.091627 |code12=-85.527029 |code13=2582661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `([0-9.-]+)`. The reason `.+` doesn't work is because `.` matches whitespace as well. The reason you can't just use `\S+` (non-spaces) is because you only want to match the numbers.

Comment: It didnt work :(, it matched the first figures one by one.. I did this. ([0-9.-]+)([0-9.-]+)([0-9.-]+)([0-9.-]+) and so on.. And then replace them by code1=\2 code2=\3... and so on

Comment: Did you use the Replace All button? It should have matched them all, but only if you used the right button.

Comment: Yeah i did, but since each figure has to have a different parameter before each figure as i mentioned above, so it works if i add the same code for each figure, like adding code1= for every numbers works.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean (didn't notice the code1,code2, etc thing). Yeah, there's no automatic way to do that with regex.

Comment: Oh, so there's no way i can add automatically a different code for each one?:(

Comment: Nope. Regex isn't a programming language, it's just a pattern *matching* engine.